# Is AFK gaming more profitable?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes you will continue to 'earn gold' but not achievements (or progression?) while the game is closed, like when I go to sleep or the like. When I return though I am always amazed at the amount of gold I have earned.

Is the amount of gold you earn increased if you close the game down for extended periods or is it just my perception of watching the incremental vs a sudden jump?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The amount of gold you receive when the game is closed is higher than the amount you receive when the game is open, assuming you are not actively playing the game.  I ran a few tests with my game and the results are as follows:

```
30 minutes game open               => 10,883q gold
30 minutes game closed             => 12,246q gold
30 minutes game open, using skills => 18,361q gold
```

I didn't do 30 minutes of clicking and using skills because that's boring.

So, if you aren't actively playing the game, close the browser tab. You'll gain more gold.

Information from v0.14

Comment: Didn't the latest update bring the gold gained when the game is closed more in-line with it being open?  I recall there being something in the patch notes about it.

Comment: @Frank - it does say "Offline gold calculation has been tweaked to be more accurate."  Not sure what that actually means, though.  Those numbers are from v0.14.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was referring to.  If you still get more gold when closed, even on the latest version, then I guess "accurate" doesn't mean more in-line with it being open.

Answer (score -1):

I have played the game and many other idle games and I know that your DPS and/or gold you are making, does not increase when you are not playing. It will actually decrease when you are not playing due to the fact that you are not clicking the monster nor activating abilities. The same rule applies to most, if not all idle games.

This is only when you are actively playing, as another answer pointed out.

Comment: You... might want to edit your post. I looked at the tag and Clicker Heroes is an *idle game*. *idol game* has an entirely different meaning (it includes something like THE iDOLM@STER)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that error, I have corrected it now.

Comment: I just wonder with the Ancients you get that increase DPS and Gold income while 'afk' if that is not the case for this game.

Comment: According to the [FAQ at Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2i31z3/faq/ckz5lq1), you do gain more gold when the game is closed.

Comment: @James there is one ancient called: Libertas, Ancient of Freedom that does increase idol gold according to Clocker Heroes Wiki (http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Ancients).

Comment: @JasonBerkan you deal more damage while you are (actively) playing because you can click the monsters and use abilities, this allows you to kill them faster and make the money for defeating the enemies more often.

Comment: @Oreo not necessarily true. Your skills all have cooldowns. Your DPS (especially if increased by Siyalatas while idle) will always be higher than your non-skill-enhanced clicks.

Comment: @Oreo are you putting the letter 'o' in words on purpose? I mean your second to last comment contains 'idol' and 'clocker heroes'

Comment: @Revolutionair nope, i am just really bad at spellong, sorry, spelling